# Crash when encode mutable map

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I got crash when try to encode to string a mutable map

```
    internal class AsyncStorageHolder(
        var manifest: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf(),
        var hasCheatedStorageDirectory: Boolean = false,
        var haveSetup: Boolean = false
    )

    private val asyncStorageHolder = IsolateState { AsyncStorageHolder() }
     private fun writeManifest() {
        val json = Json {
            encodeDefaults = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
        asyncStorageHolder.access {
            val error: CPointer<ObjCObjectVar<NSError?>>? = null
            val serialized = json.encodeToString(it.manifest) as NSString
            serialized.writeToFile(
                createStorageDirectoryPath(getManifestFilePath()),
                true,
                NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                error
            )
        }
    }
```

Log crash
DefaultAuthStateRepository.setState - setState error: kotlin.native.concurrent.FreezingException: freezing of Continuation @ 147 has failed, first blocker is vn.momo.core.modules.storage.async.AsyncStorageModuleImpl.AsyncStorageHolder@2bc5be8
[image]

Comment: please add crash stacktrace

Comment: yes I added more log and image